# Android: adding button to action bar tabs

Tags: android-actionbar, android

I am using ActionBar and ViewPager. So I have few tabs in my application. And I want to set a button just at the right of the tab icons in the action bar. So the question is to how implement this? Setting custom layout doesn't solve the problem. This layout just overlays the tab icons. I don't have screenshots, so I just use standart contacts application to demostrate what I really want to achieve:
That is before:

[image: before]

That is what I want:

[image: after]